# Fetch HTML element value from json stingrigy value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have object which i have converted using JSON.stingrify

```
{
  "_originalElementInner": "            <input type=\"file\" name=\"\" class=\"hidden\" id=\"file_input_two\" onchange=\"alertFilename(this.value,'cropped_two');\">                           <!-- <img src=\"https://dxyz.com/tmp/5bd432ed2d8dd_img3.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"> -->                                         "
}
```

From above i want to fetch "**cropped_two**", which is on

onchange=\"alertFilename(this.value,'**cropped_two**');

Here **this.value** will remain same, so if in case want to split the string .

I have tried via multiple ways by looping and other but in vain.

Anyone can help ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are going to have to try to restate your question. It's not clear what you are attempting to do.

Comment: What i really want to do is,
I have that array above which is having HTML inside.

Now from that array of HTML string, i want to get 2nd value of

**onchange=\"alertFilename(this.value,'cropped_two');**

i.e. 'cropped_two'

I want to get this value.

Comment: Will this be executed through a browser? and is it possible to use jQuery?

Comment: what `cropped_two` is supposed to mean?

Comment: Yes. Javascript

Comment: cropped_two is just a random string or we can say parameter value, that will keep changing, so in technical term i want to get 2nd parameter value which is cropped_two in this case.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: If it's changing with JavaScript just keep track of it by whatever is suppose to be generating the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want the string? I guess this would work.

```js
let o = {
  "_originalElementInner": "            <input type=\"file\" name=\"\" class=\"hidden\" id=\"file_input_two\" onchange=\"alertFilename(this.value,'cropped_two');\">                           <!-- <img src=\"https://dxyz.com/tmp/5bd432ed2d8dd_img3.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"> -->                                         "
};
const regex = /,(.*)\);/gm;
const match = regex.exec(o._originalElementInner);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a search function to find "this.value" position, then use substring function from "this.value" position + 11 to the position of ")" witch  seems to be the only ")" in the string.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to use jQuery, you can follow this approach.

```js
var obj = {"_originalElementInner": "            <input type=\"file\" name=\"\" class=\"hidden\" id=\"file_input_two\" onchange=\"alertFilename(this.value,'cropped_two');\">                           <!-- <img src=\"https://dxyz.com/tmp/5bd432ed2d8dd_img3.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"> -->                                 "},
    stringValue = '',
    // This function will be called when the event change is triggered.
    alertFilename = function(_, str) { stringValue = str;};

// Create the jQuery object and trigger the event change
// Finally remove the function from window object (This is just to remove an unsed function after execute it).
$(obj['_originalElementInner']).trigger('change'), (delete window['alertFilename']);

console.log(stringValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Ele, this also works but Will's answer is simple javascript :) but this is also new for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

If there could be several `onchange` callbacks in your code, the following code will get the one that refers to `alertFilename`, it is also faster than regexp.

```
function extractSecondArg(text) {
  // Define the pattern to look for.
  const pattern = 'onchange=\"alertFilename(this.value,'

  // Find the index of the pattern.
  const patternIndex = text.indexOf(pattern);

  if (patternIndex !== -1) {
    // Find the closing parenthesis.
    const patternEnd = ');';
    const patternEndIndex = text.indexOf(patternEnd, patternIndex);

    // Extract the second argument of the function.
    return text.substring(patternIndex + pattern.length, patternEndIndex).replace(/["']+/g, '');
  }
}
```

Here is an example of how to use it.

```
const json = {
  "_originalElementInner": "            <input type=\"file\" name=\"\" class=\"hidden\" id=\"file_input_two\" onchange=\"alertFilename(this.value,'cropped_two');\">                           <!-- <img src=\"https://dxyz.com/tmp/5bd432ed2d8dd_img3.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"> -->                                         "
};

// Extract element to search in.
const secondArg = extractSecondArg(json['_originalElementInner']);
console.log(secondArg)
```